# QTreeView not displaying data

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I have derived from QAbstractItemModel to encode my own tree of data, but the QTreeView is not displaying.

Most of the answers I saw to similar questions were solved because of wrong variable life time, so here is my code for allocation of the model:

```
ui.tvHierarchy->setModel(
    new MetaHierarchyModel(
        cutOffExtension(
            fileName.toStdString()
        )
    )
);
```

On construction the model gets its root node filled with data and later shall load more data as needed (via `fetchMore`).

I began outputting every function that is called. This is a log of the call sequence:

```
columnCount( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  1 
columnCount( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  1 
columnCount( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  1 
hasChildren( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  true 
hasChildren( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  true 
canFetchMore( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) )) 
    return  false 
rowCount( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  1 
index( 0 ,  0 ,  QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  QModelIndex(0,0,0x987aa0,MetaHierarchyModel(0xa16970) )  
hasChildren( QModelIndex(0,0,0x987aa0,MetaHierarchyModel(0xa16970) )  ) 
    return  true 
columnCount( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  1 
parent( QModelIndex(0,0,0x987aa0,MetaHierarchyModel(0xa16970) )  ) 
    return  QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) 
index( 0 ,  0 ,  QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  QModelIndex(0,0,0x987aa0,MetaHierarchyModel(0xa16970) )  
data( QModelIndex(0,0,0x987aa0,MetaHierarchyModel(0xa16970) )  ,  13 ) 
    return  "Metaparticle 1" 
columnCount( QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  1 
parent( QModelIndex(0,0,0x987aa0,MetaHierarchyModel(0xa16970) )  ) 
    return  QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) 
index( 0 ,  0 ,  QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) ) ) 
    return  QModelIndex(0,0,0x987aa0,MetaHierarchyModel(0xa16970) )  
data( QModelIndex(0,0,0x987aa0,MetaHierarchyModel(0xa16970) )  ,  13 ) 
    return  "Metaparticle 1"
```

Output of `roleNames()`:

```
QHash((0, "display")(1, "decoration")(2, "edit")(3, "toolTip")(4, "statusTip")(5, "whatsThis"))
```

The last four lines are then repeated forever (or at least until I loose my patience).
To me it looks like the root data are fetched, but they never get displayed. It is strange, that the last parameter of `data` - which is `int role`, has the value 13, which is not defined as any role (still I give back valid strings unconditionally).

Is there anything I missed when implementing this?

Comment: As a rule, you want to be as stingy as possible when returning values from your `data` function.  If you check [the docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum), you can see that role 13 is `Qt::SizeHintRole` - I'd imagine your view is getting rather confused when that returns a string!

Comment: @XavierHolt You are right. I changed this after it did not work, when I was returning only on the DisplayRole and an `QVariant()` else. Presumably I had another error back then and now was having this problem all the way. Would you please post it as an answer, so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Great!  Glad that worked - I'll have an answer up in a minute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [QAbstractItemModel::data](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) function should be as stingy as possible with the data it returns.  Make sure you only return data when you have an exact match on the [display role](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) and column number.  In all other cases just return an invalid [QVariant](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html) (just call the default constructor), and your view widget will fill in these missing values with sensible defaults.